# What am I doing wrong with this Inline module test?

Tags: perl

UPDATE: appologies for the wrong place I chose to put stuff. I didn't notice those adds @Sinan mentioned at all probably they had been blocked by my browser. Anyway I've deleted the links now. and thank you guys :)

In my [previous post][1], @daotoad mentioned an Inline module. Now I'm playing around with it. Well, actually except for Perl, I basically know nothing about any other programming languages. The script is written for pure fun. I want to see if I can just throw to my Perl script some code written in other programming language and somehow get it working.

Well, I copied a CPP source code which I found on the Net to my Perl script and I've been trying to get it working but all I get is a screenful of error message:
It looks like something's suspicious with the imported CPP libary but I'm not sure. The following information is part of the error information that caught my eyes:

```
E:/solarlunar.h:53: error: expected identifier before "false"
E:/solarlunar.h:53: error: expected `}' before "false"
E:/solarlunar.h:53: error: expected unqualified-id before "false"
E:/solarlunar.h:53: error: expected declaration before '}' token
In file included from _3_pl_62cb.xs:19:
E:/solarlunar.h:1:1: unterminated #ifndef
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.

A problem was encountered while attempting to compile and install your Inline
CPP code. The command that failed was:
  nmake > out.make 2>&1
```

I've checked the 53rd line of solarlunar.h file and after a little bit of google about what it might mean I think this line looks pretty innocent but well as a complete C++ newbie I'm not sure:

```
**typedef enum boolean { false = 0, true = 1 } boolean;**
```

**I've tried compiling and testing the C++ code with DEV-C++ and everything worked like expected.**

My script (updated) is this:

```
    #Inline-Test.pl
 use warnings;
 use Inline 'CPP' => Config => LIBS => 'E:/';
    use Inline 'CPP' => Config => INC  => 'E:/';
 use Inline 'CPP';

    my $args = <STDIN>;     
 chomp $args;
    my $result = main($args); 
    print $result;

__END__
__CPP__


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "solarlunar.h"
#include "solarlunar.c"

/**//* input format: sl -[s|l]   year.month.day */
/**//* the lunar calendar date range is limited by solarlunar.h: 1899/12/1 ~ 2099.12.30 */

static void usage(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int year, month, day;
    int i;
    /**//* convert flag, 0: solar convert to luanr. 1: lunar convert solar */
    int convert_f = 0;
    solar_calendar so;
    lunar_calendar lu;

    /**//* input check */
    if( argc < 3 || argv[1][0]!= '-' ||
         !(argv[1][2] == 's' || argv[1][3] == 'l')) {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }

    /**//* get convert flag */
    convert_f = (argv[1][4] == 's' ? 0 : 1);

    /**//* converting */
    for(i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        sscanf(argv[i], "%d.%d.%d", &year, &month, &day);
        switch(convert_f) ...{
            case 0:
                so = solar_creat_date(year, month, day);
                lu = solar2lunar(so);
                printf("%d.%d.%d ", lunar_get_year(lu), lunar_get_month(lu), lunar_get_day(lu));
                break;
            case 1:
                lu = lunar_creat_date(year, month, day);
                so = lunar2solar(lu);
                printf("%d.%d.%d ", solar_get_year(so), solar_get_month(so), solar_get_day(so));
                break;
            default :
                exit(2);
        }
    }
        return 0;
}


static void usage(void)
{
    printf("sl -[s|l] year1.month1.day1 year2.month2.day2 ... "
            "-s: solar calendar date convert to lunar calendar date. "
            "-l: lunar calendar date convert to lunar calendar date.");
}
```

The necessary library can be downloaded from [here] and [here].
Sorry, wrong place to put stuff. links now deleted.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the file `solarlunar.h` -- can you show us that file?

Comment: @mobrule, thanks :) just checked and the source code of solarlunar.h looks a little long but I'll get it posted right away. But if this solarulunar.h is the culprit, I guess it's quite beyond my ability to get the problem fixed :(

Comment: If you don't know C++, trying to use `Inline::CPP` is likely to be an exercise in frustration.  I'd learn the other language before trying to use it with `Inline`.

Comment: @cjm, I'm just doing it for fun. Isn't it amazing that we can just throw some code written by someone else in some other language to our Perl script and somehow get it working :) Anyway I'm learning along the way of doing such things :)

Comment: Mike, if you want to wrap a piece of C++ code in anger, I suggest using plain XS or even XS++ (ExtUtils::XSpp). Both require a familiarity with the language, however.

Comment: My guess is that at line 53 of solarlunar.h, the compiler expects there to be an identifier.  Probably before the word "false".

Comment: Also, why are you calling "use Inline" three times?  Where did you get the idea to do this, and why not just call it once?

Comment: @jrockway, thanks for the comment. I'll see if I can simplify that use line. Thanks :)

Comment: @jrockway, I checked the 53rd line of the .h file. It is this: "typedef enum boolean { false = 0, true = 1} boolean;". I'll see if I can figure out what it means.

Comment: By the way, I must **strongly** object to the host you decided to use to link to those files. I do not enjoy ads for adult services popping up all over the place. Next time, find a less offensive place to put stuff.

Comment: I just noticed your claim that the behavior you are seeing must be due to a bug in `Inline::CPP`. That is idiotic: You do not know `C`, you do not know `C++`. You seem to barely know Perl. Even then, you cannot be doing something wrong. It must be the fault of the library or the compiler! That attitude is the mark of a bad programmer.

Comment: @Sinan, my appologies for the bad place I chose to put stuff. I didn't notice any adult ads there at all probably due to the fact those ads are being blocked by my browser. Anyway it's my fault and I appologize and I'll delete the link right away.

Comment: @Sinan, I don't call myself programmer because I'm not. I'm just a happy and silly Perl learner :)

Comment: @Sinan, by the way, I had also been aware that the problem might be related to the compiler. But you can't always say everything at once. I'm now thinking when I was suggesting that Inline CPP might be buggy, it might sound offensive to the author, to whom I should actually be saying thank you. Well my appologies. Actually recently I've been having a lot of buggy modules and programs.

Comment: @Sinan, btw, this is not right "you are seeing must be due to a bug in Inline::CPP", I said "a bug maybe" :)

Comment: @Mike There probably are bugs in `Inline::CPP`. However, the first paragraph of your post cannot include **I'm suspecting there's something wrong with the `Inline::CPP` module** when there are so many other explanations for your script's failure (e.g. the fact that you do not know enough `C` or `C++` to recognize that the code you are trying to compile is `C` and not `C++`). See also 
http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#id382249

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for the link. Yes yes don't rush to claim that you have found a bug unless you can prove it. I'll be trying to ask smart questions. Well, maybe I should explain this: I think it's a fact some Perl modules do not work in a stable way in Windows and when I say something is wrong, it could be some kind of compatibility problem, I mean it's the limitation that the authors are aware of, not necessarily a bug.

Comment: @jrockaway Sorry to follow up years later; I just noticed the comment about invoking `use Inline 'CPP'` three times.  It's actually perfectly legitimate to do that when passing configuration parameters to Inline::CPP.  It's in the POD for Inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are trying to compile C source code as C++. The author of this silly program seems want a boolean type in C and therefore defines it using an enumeration:

```
typedef enum boolean { false = 0, true = 1} boolean;
```

Now, this trips up a C++ compiler because that language has a `bool` type and `true` and `false` are values for that type. The assignment `false = 0` is not valid C++.

It is interesting that the word `boolean` only appears in one place in `solarlunar.c`:

```
boolean is_leap_year(const int year)
{
    return LEAP(ABS(year));
}
```

changing that function's return type to `int` and getting rid of the `typedef` in `solarlunar.h` should solve the immediate issue. Compiling the source code as `C` using `gcc` resulted in no errors even without those changes.

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for posting this answer. It sounds like the answer :) Thanks and thanks for the harsh criticism you posted.

Comment: @Sinan, it still does not work. Like you suggested, I used int is_leap_year(const int year){return LEAP(ABS(year));} in the .c file and in the .h file I deleted the 53rd line that contains boolean and the 64th line that also contains boolean is_leap_year(const int year) but it is still not working :( Windows console threw me some different error messages. I'm wondering whether you have tested the script on Unix or Windows. Thanks.

Comment: and it does not work if I change in the 64th line of .h file boolean is_leap_year(const int year) to int is_leap_year(const int year)

Comment: @Sinan, can you kindly claify this "Compiling the source code as C using gcc resulted in no errors"? I mean have you tested the Inline::CPP module?  I can't get my Perl script working. But like I said I had successfully compiled the C++ source code using DEV-C++. Now I let the Perl script use C compiler to comile the wrapped source, but I still can't get it working :(

Comment: @Mike I compiled `solarlunar.c` from the `cmd.exe` shell using `gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)` (which I installed using `ppm`). By default, `gcc` treats files with extension `.c` as `C` source, not `C++`, and therefore, the definition of the `boolean` enum did not cause any errors (there were a couple warnings, but the code is a little amateurish anyway). In any case, I do not understand why you insist on using `Inline::CPP` when you are trying to use `C` code. The right way to go about this is to compile `solarlunar.c` and then link to it. But, I am not motivated to work it out.

Comment: @Sinan, thank you for the explanation. Looks like using the "C" compiler in my Perl script can get the source "C++" code working just fine. The problem I'm now facing is, I've realized, caused by the fact that I lack a good understanding of Perl. But I'll get it working anyway, I'm sure :)

Comment: @Sinan, the "C++" code I'm using is copied from a website that says "it's C++ code" and the problem is I can't tell the difference between C++ and C. I'm just having fun with Perl :) and want to learn.

Comment: @Sinan, I actually wrote some time ago a pure Perl program without using any module that can convert between solar and lunar calendar and do some other stuff. my code is probably very ugly though. the thing is I just want to have fun and gain Perl experience.

Comment: @Sinan, although I'm still having trouble with this Inline thing, my original problem is gone. Answer happily accepted and thanks again :)

Comment: @Sinan, looks like the Inline::C module cannot handle "int main(int argc, char *argv[])" that appears in the wrapped C code, so I have to give up on it for now.